# how to get XML from a stored procedure in coldfusion

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, coldfusion

I'm trying to output a stored procedure from Sql Server into an output of a coldfusion page.  The coldfusion page calls the stored procedure correctly, but only part of the data is returned (xml is truncated).  When I call the stored procedure within sql server, it gives the entire XML document with no fails.  I'm wondering if Coldfusion has a limit, or am I not working the code correctly.

Here's the stored procedure:

```
USE [myschema]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GEOIDKMLZIP]    Script Date: 9/18/2015 10:28:40 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GEOIDKMLZIP] @Zip int
AS
DECLARE @kml XML
DECLARE @kmlout NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @kml = CAST(concat('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>',
'<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">',
'<Document>',
'       <Style id="Licensed">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff000000</color>
                <width>2</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>1e1400FF</color>
                <fill>1</fill>
                <outline>1</outline>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style id="NotLicensed">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff000000</color>
                <width>2</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>1e14F0FF</color>
                <fill>1</fill>
                <outline>1</outline>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style id="Other">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>ff000000</color>
                <width>2</width>
            </LineStyle>
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>1e007800</color>
                <fill>1</fill>
                <outline>1</outline>
            </PolyStyle>
        </Style>' ,
(
            select 

                '<![CDATA[{"Zip":"' + z.ZipCode + '", "GEOID": "'+ z.GEOID+'"}]]>' as name,
                case t.IsLicensed
                    when 2 then '#Licensed'
                    when 1 then '#NotLicensed'
                    else '#Other'
                end as styleUrl, 
                polygons as Geometry
        from ZipCodeGEOID z
        join Tracts t on t.GEOID = z.GEOID
        join census_county_ref c on t.GEOID = c.GEOID
        where z.ZipCode = @Zip
FOR XML PATH('Placemark'), ELEMENTS), '</Document></kml>') AS XML)
--
-- Perform replacement of &lt; and &gt; with < and > respectively
--
SET @kmlout = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(@kml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>'), '<Geometry>', ''), '</Geometry>', '')
SET @kmlout = REPLACE(@kmlout, 'utf-16', 'utf-8')
--
-- Return kmlout
--
SELECT @kmlout as kml
```

and here's zip2tractkml.cfm

```
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="yes">
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/xml">
<cfstoredproc procedure="GEOIDKMLZIP" datasource="buyerhero">
    <cfprocparam value="#URL.ZIP#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">

    <!--- One resultset is returned called "qEmployees" --->
    <cfprocresult name="response" resultset="1">
</cfstoredproc>
<cfset kml = XmlParse(response.kml)>
<cfoutput>#kml#</cfoutput>
```

I also tried just outputing the result with out the cfset:

```
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="yes">
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/xml">

<cfstoredproc procedure="GEOIDKMLZIP" datasource="buyerhero">
    <cfprocparam value="#URL.ZIP#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">

    <!--- One resultset is returned called "qEmployees" --->
    <cfprocresult name="kml" resultset="1">
</cfstoredproc>

<cfoutput>#kml.kmlout#</cfoutput>
```

but I got the same response (truncated xml).  again, when I run this in SQL Server using:

```
EXEC    [dbo].[GEOIDKMLZIP]
        @Zip = N'53554'


GO
```

It works like a charm, and the XML is formatted properly.
What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of truncation happens? Is the xml still valid? Is it only the first subnode of the xml? You could check the _real_ data that MSSQL returns with wireshark.

Comment: The way the sproc rolls gives the xml in one single block, tags and all.  When cf pulls it.  It stops at some random point along the way without explanation

Comment: Did you check your datasource settings to ensure [CLOB/long text retrieval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075215/retreving-long-text-clob-using-cfquery) is enabled?

Comment: That was it.  You are awesome.  Can you put that in an answer block so I can give it credit?  Thx

Comment: Thanks, but since an answer already exists, best to just close this thread as a dupe and vote up the existing answer :)

Comment: How do you close a thread?